# Drop duplicates over time window in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a streaming data frame in spark reading from a kafka topic and I want to drop duplicates for the past 5 minutes every time a new record is parsed.

I am aware of the `dropDuplicates(["uid"])` function, I am just not sure how to check for duplicates over a specific historic time interval.

My understanding is that the following:

```
df = df.dropDuplicates(["uid"])
```

either works on the data read over the current (micro)batch or else over "anything" that is right now into memory.
Is there a way to set the time for this de-duplication, using a `"timestamp"` column within the data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df\
  .withWatermark("event_time", "5 seconds")\
  .dropDuplicates(["User", "uid"])\
  .groupBy("User")\
  .count()\
  .writeStream\
  .queryName("pydeduplicated")\
  .format("memory")\
  .outputMode("complete")\
  .start()
```

for more info you can refer,
https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/17/arbitrary-stateful-processing-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html